# Changing the title of "<- back to" website in wp-login.php

Tags: wp-login-form

The login form on the page wp-login.php has a title at the bottom that says "<- Back to website-name" This title then always redirects to the home page, but I want the title just reading "back to website-name" so I just want the "<-" removed.

I imagine this requires a hook added to functions.php but I'm not sure how and could not find anything while searching online.

Any suggestions please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please add below code to your `functions.php` to remove the `&larr;` from the translated string:

```
/**
 * Remove &larr; from the '&larr; Back to %s' translation
 */
add_action( 'login_init', function()
{
    add_filter( 'gettext', 'wpse_back_to_site_text', 10, 2 );
} );

function wpse_back_to_site_text( $translated, $untranslated )
{
    // Target the untranslated string
    if( '&larr; Back to %s' === $untranslated )
    {
        // Remove the filter callback
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

        // Modify the translation
        $translated = __( 'Back to %s' );
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

where we initiate our custom `gettext` filter callback, to run only within the `login_init` hook, to restrict it to the login page.

For details please follow [source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-login-footer-back-to-blog-text) and [details](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext)

Comment: What about wrapping this instead into the `login_init` hook, as the `gettext` is an "expensive" filter and remove it as soon as we have a match. I think we can skip the string replacement as well, and just assign it the new string value.

Comment: Thanks for useful information, you can update or provide answer!!

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly (ps. `wp-register.php` was removed from core years ago, see [#18544](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18544))

Comment: Thanks for improving with better approach and useful deatils @birgire

Comment: Thanks for the assistance! Can you care to explain how you figured this out as I found it rather difficult to take on myself.